# What are the best practices for backing up a secured SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2012, ssl

I want to state right off the bat that I'm not looking for information on how to backup a SQL Server. I've got that taken care of.

I'm looking for some form of documentation that will tell me the steps I need to take/things I need to keep in mind to properly back up a secured (with a 3rd party certificate) SQL Server 2012.

What, other than the actual database information, do I need to send to my backup solution so I can ensure minimal downtime in a worst case scenario (knock on wood)?

Comment: Have you had a read through this? The only reason I ask is because if so then I probably wouldn't post an answer, and if you haven't I recommend that you do. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964742.aspxb964742.aspx

Comment: It says 'Content Not Found' when clicked.

Comment: I have updated the link for you now - sorry about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964742.aspx

Comment: Ok this I have taken care of but in addition to this I applied a SSL certificate to the server.  Unless specifically noted, I don't see how this applies to the SSL scenario.  One of my biggest gripes about this product is the lack of good, detailed documentation from MSFT about encrypting a SQL server with a 3rd party SSL and all processes/procedures associated with this including backups.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused - in your question you say that it is secured with a 3rd party certificate then below you say SSL. Are you talking about database encryption or an encrypted transport layer? What exactly is secured with the certificate and how is that certificate used?

Answer (score 1):

There's different things you can do with certificates: you can use them to encrypt endpoint communications (like mirroring or AlwaysOn Availability Groups), or you can use them to encrypt databases with Transparent Data Encryption (TDE).

If you're using them to encrypt endpoint communications, just back up the certificates once and keep them in a safe place. I wouldn't expect shops to routinely rotate those certificates.

If you're using them with Transparent Data Encryption, back up both the certificate and the key as described in Books Online:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

With TDE, though, you should routinely rotate the keys. Otherwise, when anybody steals the certificate and key, then they can decrypt all of the backups going forward. When you rotate the key, you'll want to immediately back that up again. You can't run backups while the database is re-encrypting with the new key, but back it up again as soon as the re-encryption process is done.